# Does it Oracle DB exist gap lock concept such as Mysql?

Tags: oracle

Does it Oracle DB exist gap lock concept such as Mysql?
If gap lock doesn't exists in Oracle, how to resolve the phantom read?

Comment: I think you can read about dirty reads here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/server.1111/e25789/consist.htm or here http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_isolation_level.htm and this is some good discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61772555/the-right-isolation-level

Comment: All the information you want is probably found in the Oracle documentation [Data Concurrency and Consistency](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/cncpt/data-concurrency-and-consistency.html#GUID-3DA63BF3-5C19-4DBC-8E6B-980771AEA2FB)